# How to make a POJO "Parcelable" if one of the POJO's fields is another POJO

Tags: java, serialization, parcelable, pojo

Title says it all, say I have this class construction:

```
public class MyParentObject implements Comparable, Parcelable {
    private String param1, param2, param3, param4, param5;
    private Integer param6, param7;
    private double param8, param9;
    private InnerObject myChildObject = new InnerObject("test data");

//Other methods and constructors

}
```

If there is an inner object that is "not" parcelable, do I have to implement that as well?

Here is my structure:

```
Class A
   - Class B
      - ArrayList<Class C>
      - List<Class D>
```

Here is what I have implemented so far:

Class A:

```
 public A (Parcel in) {
    String[] data = new String[11];
    in.readStringArray(data);
    this.stringParam1 = data[0];
    this.stringParam2 = data[1];
    this.stringParam3 = data[2];
    this.stringParam4 = data[3];
    this.stringParam5 = data[4];
    this.integerParam1 = Integer.valueOf(data[5]);
    this.integerParam2 = Integer.valueOf(data[6]);
    this.doubleParam1 = Double.valueOf(data[7]);
    this.doubleParam2 = Double.valueOf(data[8]);
    this.booleanParam1 = Boolean.getBoolean(data[10]);

    this.classBParam = in.readParcelable(B.class.getClassLoader());
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(stringParam1);
    dest.writeString(stringParam2);
    dest.writeString(stringParam3);
    dest.writeString(stringParam4);
    dest.writeString(stringParam5);
    dest.writeString(Integer.toString(integerParam1));
    dest.writeString(Integer.toString(integerParam2));
    dest.writeString(Double.toString(doubleParam1));
    dest.writeString(Double.toString(doubleParam2));
    dest.writeString(Boolean.toString(booleanParam1));
    dest.writeParcelable(classBParam,flags);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public A createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new A(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Object[0];
    }
};
```

Comment: You can create an annotation for the fields those should be cared separately in parceling operation and use and interpret that annotation.

Comment: Sorry how do you mean. If I need the `InnerObject` to be passed through an intent along with the `ParentObject`, I can't just ignore the field?

Comment: I changed my comment, you don't necessarily need to exclude it, I meant the fields those should be interpreted differently.

Comment: I see. Mind if I try to write up an implementation then post it for some feedback?

Comment: @Juvanis so I added a bit on the parceling on the CLASS A as well as a little diagram to show the nesting structure. How would I then call the parcelization on class `B`?